# Display different Icon in table column based in ng-repeat value

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm trying to modify old code that displays a table and allows the Administrator to toggle between allowing and disallowing updates for the item selected.  Based on if the update flag is already set to *true*, then clicking an icon should toggle it to *false* (and vice versa).  What I want to do, however, is display a different icon based on the value of the update flag.  Here is the code I have so far (displaying only one icon for the "toggle" action):

```
<tr ng-repeat="s in series">
    @if (isAdmin)
    {
        <td ng-click="actions.remove($index)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger" title='Delete this series'></span>
        </td>
        <td ng-click="actions.toggle($index)" class="editable-click" style="text-align: center">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle text-warning" title='Enable/Disable updates for this series'></span>
        </td>
    }
    <td>{{s.ReleaseYear}}</td>
    <td>{{s.TitleId}}</td>
    <td>{{s.TitleName}}</td>
</tr>
```

The second column is dispalying the "ban circle" icon and that's what I want for the icon if the flag (**{{s.EnableSeriesUpdates}}**) is *true* (i.e. enabled).  I want to change that to a different icon if the flag is *false* (i.e. disabled) to visually indicate wanting to re-enable updates.

Is there some way to do this in a if/else statement by checking the value of the **{{s.EnableSeriesUpdates}}** flag?  I tried to do something like that but it wouldn't recognize the value of the flag (probably because I don't know how to get that value in this context) and my searches on how to do it came up empty.  I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a different icon based on the value of the `EnableSeriesUpdates` flag, you can use the AngularJS `ng-class` directive along with an inline if/else statement.

The code will look like:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="s in series">
    @if (isAdmin)
    {
        <td ng-click="actions.remove($index)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger" title='Delete this series'></span>
        </td>
        <td ng-click="actions.toggle($index)" class="editable-click" style="text-align: center">
            <span ng-class="{'glyphicon-ban-circle': s.EnableSeriesUpdates, 'glyphicon-check': !s.EnableSeriesUpdates}" 
                  class="glyphicon" ng-attr-title="{{s.EnableSeriesUpdates ? 'Disable updates for this series' : 'Enable updates for this series'}}"></span>
        </td>
    }
    <td>{{s.ReleaseYear}}</td>
    <td>{{s.TitleId}}</td>
    <td>{{s.TitleName}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment because the error was mine.  I have corrected that and your solution works perfectly.  Thank you!